# Accuracy is getting worse after text pre processing

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, text-classification

I'm working a multi-class text classification project.

After splitting the dataset into train and test datasets, I've applied the below function on the train dataset (AKA pre processing):

```
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def clean_text(text):   
    # lowercase text
    text = text.lower() 
    
    # delete bad symbols
    text = re.sub(r"(@\[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)|^rt|http.+?", "", text)  
  
    # delete stopwords from text
    text = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if word not in STOPWORDS) 

    # Stemming the words
    text = ' '.join([stemmer.stem(word) for word in text.split()])
    
    return text
```

To my surprise, I've got much worst results (i.e. va_accuracy) applying on the train dataset rather than just "do nothing" (59% vs 69%)

I've literally commented out the apply line in the below section:

```
all_data = dataset.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
train_df, valid = train_test_split(all_data, test_size=0.2)

train_df['text'] = train_df['text'].apply(clean_text)
```

What am I missing?
How can it be that pre processing steps decreased accuracy?

**A bit more info**

I forgot to mention I'm using the below to tokenize the text:

```
X_train = train.iloc[:, :-1]
y_train = train.iloc[:, -1:]
X_test = valid.iloc[:, :-1]
y_test = valid.iloc[:, -1:]

weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight='balanced', classes=np.unique(y_train), 
                                            y=y_train.values.reshape(-1))
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(weights)
class_weights_dict = dict(zip(le.transform(list(le.classes_)), weights))


tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size, oov_token='<OOV>')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train['text'])

train_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train['text'])
train_padded = pad_sequences(train_seq, maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)

validation_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test['text'])
validation_padded = pad_sequences(validation_seq, maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)
```

Later on I'm fitting all into the model as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=train_padded.shape[1]))

model.add(Conv1D(48, len(GROUPS), activation='relu', padding='valid'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(len(GROUPS), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs = 100
batch_size = 32

history = model.fit(train_padded, training_labels, shuffle=True ,
                    epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
                    class_weight=class_weights_dict,
                    validation_data=(validation_padded, validation_labels),
                    callbacks=[ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=5, min_lr=0.0001), 
                               EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=2, verbose=1),
                               EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', patience=5, verbose=1)])
```

Comment: Did you run tests to make sure that your clean_text function really does what you believe it does?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate this hypothesis / debug which step is reducing accuracy: fix the train/test split and try turning on and off each of your four preprocessing steps, keeping the other three turned on.  Fix the training/test split and run your classification scheme.  Repeat for each preprocessing step.  Then compare.

If I had to guess - the stemming step is creating your issue (lower accuracy).

```
    # Stemming the words
    text = ' '.join([stemmer.stem(word) for word in text.split()])
```

Stemming makes text with subtle (and sometimes not so subtle) differences (e.g., suffixes) exactly the same.  This can make the vector representations of text from your various classes more similar than they would be otherise - potentially making it harder to distinguish them from each other - and consequently making your classification accuracy worse.

Comment: Indeed when commenting out the above line I've ended up with 67%, but it's still lower

Comment: which line produces the greatest accuracy hit?  are you fixing the train/test split when you're making the comparison - so when turning on/off each line you're using the same train/test datasets?  what does the data - classified correctly under one cleaning regime, but then incorrectly under another - look like?  both before - and after cleaning?

Comment: I've updated my question with additional info